# How to make my label one-third of my UITableViewCell through auto-layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, aspect-ratio

I have a TableView inside my View Controller and inside my TableView, I have a Custom UTableView Cell. I want to have a label one-third or my custom tableview cell, but when I drag by right clicking on my label to the content view (Of my cell) to select aspect ratio, I don't get the aspect ratio option. Can anyone please help me to figure out ho to make my label to be one-third of my tableview cell.

I set the constrain for trailing space and top space to container.
[image]

Now, when I go to find the aspect ratio, I don't get any.

[image]

Comment: Try embeding it in a view that fills the whole Content view. Then set the aspect ratio to that parent view of the UILabel.

Comment: I don't think aspect ratio is what you want anyway.  You should set a constraint for your label to have equal width to the content view with a multiplier of 1/3

Comment: in these kind of cases, i put another view with contentview's same size and set constraints with that. It worked for me since now. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes that worked. I put a container view with the cell height and width and the I used equal width to make it 1/3 rd of my view. Thanks  lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to @dreaming-in-binary's answer, IB may not allow you to set an equal width constraint against the content view (even though it is possible programmatically). Instead you could add a hidden reference view which spans the full width of the cell (i.e., has leading and trailing constraints to the content view with a constant of 0, and any vertical constraints). Then you can set your equal width constraint (really a proportional width constraint) against the reference view instead.

Comment: Alternatively, constrain the label to be half the size of the textfield, and ensure they have a horizontal space constraint with each other and to the near edge of their superview.

Answer (score 4):

Aspect ratio probably isn't the best for this. You should drag from the `UILabel` to your content view and select an **equal width** constraint. Then, open the attributes for it and change the **multiplier** to .33.

Comment: I tried that too. When I drag from Uilabel to The Tableviewcell's content view, I can't find any "equal width" constraint.

Comment: In that case, how many labels do you have in there? Your question says you want it 1/3, but in IB you only have two labels.

Comment: @natasha You don't make that constraint by dragging. You need to hold down the command key, select your label, then select the view so both are selected. Then, in the pin menu, choose "equal widths".

Comment: Did it work when you added the .33 multiplier to that constraint?

Comment: I had to add a view inside the cell to have the equal width or the aspect ratio constraint. Then it worked.